# table view cell restore normal status after actions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using Objective-C. Here I have a tableview, and I set some actions using this method:

```
- (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

So when I slide the cell, it looks like this: [the cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCZHF.png)

I want to dismiss these action buttons after I clicked on one of them. Which method should I use?

Comment: What do you mean by "dismiss": disable or hide or something else?

Comment: dismiss means hide, and Paruru's answer to this already helped me out, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

These code will do well:
            [tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];